# python-docx - remove document content (paragraphs / tables) from a given line | split document by line

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a docx file and I need to remove all content from a given line.

From what I can see I can iterate over paragraphs or tables.

However I think that I need some universal element to iterate over to remove all content from a specific point (element) in the document.

Next I would like to check if this element is a paragraph or a table to execute relevant deletion code.

I have found this code in [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-77661907) for deleting a paragraph (which doesn't seem to work anymore):

```py
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
    p = paragraph._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)
    paragraph._p = paragraph._element = None
```

but I can still delete paragraph runs:

```py
runs = paragraph.runs
for run in runs:
    run.text = ""
    r = run._r
    r.getparent().remove(r)
```

Didn't tested, but I have seen code for deleting table content somewhere.

So, is it possible to perform such an action?

Alternative description of what I want to achieve would be to split existing document by line with tag  ex. `spit here`.

Comment: I'm on my way to a solution based on [Kanarsky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063116/12273839)